# Java concurrent API Lock vs Synchronized on shared resources

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to replace the simple Java thread code with its concurrent lock API.
It might be the silly thing to ask it here, but i tried by my self and could not get any success.
I have following classes.
Hotel.java

```
public class Hotel implements Runnable {
    private Item item;

    Hotel(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (item) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Ordered item = " + item.name);
                Cook cook = new Cook(item);
                Thread t = new Thread(cook);
                t.start();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                item.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("total bill: " + item.price);
        }
    }

}
```

Cook.java

```
public class Cook implements Runnable {

    private Item item;

    Cook(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (item) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Cooked item = " + item.name);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            item.notify();
        }

    }
}
```

and Item.java

```
public class Item {

    String name;
    double price;

    public Item(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

I have following Main.java class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Item item = new Item("Burger", 100.00);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Hotel(item));
        t.start();

    }

}
```

When I run this Main class I get below output.

```
Ordered item = Burger
Cooked item = Burger
total bill: 100.0
```

I want to replace this code using concurrent Lock API of jdk1.5.
I tried to use Lock instead of synchronized keyword, But I was not able to lock the item in two different classes(i.e. Hotel and Cook) using ReentrantLock. Since the Item is a shared resource between Hotel and Cook I should be able to lock it. I got IllegalMonitorStateException Exception.

Comment: What have you tried and where have you failed?

Comment: So the hotel asks the cook to cook an item, and then when the cook is finished the hotel serves the item and prints the bill.  Is that what this is supposed to do?

Comment: yes correct. And it should be in the order.

Comment: @alfasin , I tried to use Lock instead of synchronized keyword, But I was not able to lock the item in two different classes using ReentrantLock. Since the Item is a shared resource between Hotel and Cook I should be able to lock it. I got IllegalMonitorStateException Exceptions.

Comment: Just FYI, I think you could easily make `Item` immutable, which is much better in concurrency than trying to protect it with a lock (or protect it with synchronization).  When designing for concurrency, always use immutable objects if reasonably possible.

Comment: @markspace, Yes you are right, this is one way of making sure the object is thread safe. But here the issue I am facing with is the order in which the Item class should be accessed. It should like
" the hotel asks the cook to cook an item, and then when the cook is finished the hotel serves the item and prints the bill"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that you also need to use

```
java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition
```

Essentially you can replace

```
java.lang.Object.wait(); and
java.lang.Object.notify();
```

with

```
java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition.await(); and
java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition.signal().
```

So if you change Item to

```
public class Item {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    String name;
    ...
}
```

You can replace

```
synchronized (item) {
    ...
    item.wait();
}
```

with

```
item.lock.lock();
try {
    ...
    item.condition.await();
} finally {
     item.lock.unlock();
}
```

and replace:

```
synchronized (item) {
    ...
    item.notify();
}
```

with

```
item.lock.lock();
try {
    ...
    item.condition.signal();
} finally {
     item.lock.unlock();
}
```